# How do I prove that the composition of an affine function preserves convexity?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What would be the formal proof that $ f(Ax + b) $ given $ f(x) $ is a convex function ?
I got to the point where I expanded
$$
f(\lambda(Ax+b) + (1- \lambda)(Ay+b)) = f(A(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) + b)
$$
Though I do not know how to proceed to incorporate the convexity of $f(x)$.

Comment: The convexity of $f$ gives you an upper bound of the left hand side.

Comment: True. But how would I bound it to be less that $\lambda f(Ax+b) + (1-\lambda)f(Ay+b) $

Comment: That is _exactly_ what the convexity of $f$ gives you.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps the concreteness of writing $f(Ax+b)$ shadows the important matter. Let us simply denote the affine map by $g$, and see how we can deduce that if $f$ is convex, then $f\circ g$ is also convex.

We need to show that for any $x,y$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we have

$$(f\circ g)\left(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\right) \leqslant \lambda (f\circ g)(x) + (1-\lambda)(f\circ g)(y).$$

Now, the characteristic property of affine maps is that

$$g\left(tx + (1-t)y\right) = t\cdot g(x) + (1-t)\cdot g(y)$$

for all $x,y$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. So we have

$$\begin{align}
(f\circ g)\left(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \right) &= f\left(g\left(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \right) \right)\\
&= f\left(\lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda)g(y) \right)\\
&\leqslant \lambda f\left(g(x)\right) + (1-\lambda)f\left( g(y)\right),
\end{align}$$

which is exactly what we need.